# Как лучше всего осуществить систему ходов с ИИ в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, искусственный-интеллект

Я занимаюсь созданием простой игры-стратегии с имитацией искусственного интеллекта и недавно столкнулся с проблемой того, что не до конца понимаю как осуществить систему ходов в игре.

Необходимо создать систему ходов, чтобы после того как я выполнил некое действие - переместился на клетку вперед, восстановил здоровье и т.д., у игрока отключалось управление и действие переходило к выполнению алгоритма имитирующего ИИ противника)

Думал, что в теории можно решить задачу с помощью корутина(WaitFor, WaitUntil), но я не уверен, что это правильное решение в данной ситуации.
Хотел бы получить мнение по поводу более элегантного решения этой задачи.

Comment: не могу понять, проблема отключить управление?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не понимаю каким образом система ходов должна работать. Действительно ли стоит использовать корутин или есть более элегантное решение?

Comment: Когда я писал стандартные крестики-нолики, я после каждого действия пользователя проверял- выиграл ли он текущим ходом, если нет, то я вызывал функцию которая делала ход компьютера, и снова проверял является ли ход выигрышным. В это время блокировал все вызовы от игрока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, вам подойдут события. При выполнении определенного действия вызываете ранее объявленное событие , а в нужном классе подписываетесь на него.

```
public class MyMove: MonoBehaviour
...
        public delegate void EndTurn();
        public event EndTurn EndTurnEvent;
    // действия...
    // сделал ход, запустил событие
            if (AttackButtonEvent != null)
            {
              EndTurnEvent();
            }
    // поправил здоровье, запустил событие
            if (AttackButtonEvent != null)
            {
              EndTurnEvent();
            } // и т.д.
```

А в другом классе подписываешься на событие и запускаешь действие ИИ (там уже как у вас игровая логика построена).

```
public class RobotMove: MonoBehaviour
...
// подписываешься на событие
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        MyMove.EndTurnEvent += RobotDoSomeThing;
    }
// собственно действие
    private void RobotDoSomeThing()
    {
       // действия (запуск корутины или как у вас игровая логика построена)
    }
// и не забыть отписаться от события
    private void OnDisable()
    {
     MyMove.EndTurnEvent -= RobotDoSomeThing;
    }
```

Подробнее про события (event) можно прочитать [тут](https://habr.com/post/213809/), [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.14.php) и [тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level10/10_7.php).